# PHP statement for time expiry

Tags: php

The listings on my site have three states:
- Active
- Sold
- Expired

I wrote this to get listings that are in Active or Sold to automatically expire if they pass a certain date.

```
<span class="detail">Status: <?php 
    if(strtotime($property['data']['field_3211']) < time()){ echo 'Expired'; }
    else if($property['raw']['field_3022'] == 5) echo 'Active';
    else if($property['raw']['field_3022'] == 8 ) echo 'Sold'; 
    else echo 'Not set';
    ?>
</span>
```

I now want to change it to only expire if the status is set to active and ignore the expiry if it is set to sold.

Comment: Having a lookup-table for the labels associated with those codes would help clean this up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is specify in the `if` that outputs the Expired message that the record must be active as well as `< time()`.

```
<span class="detail">Status: 
<?php 
    if(strtotime($property['data']['field_3211']) < time() &&
        $property['raw']['field_3022'] == 5) 
    { 
        echo 'Expired'; 
    }
    else if($property['raw']['field_3022'] == 5) {
        echo 'Active';
    }
    else if($property['raw']['field_3022'] == 8 ) {
        echo 'Sold'; 
    }
    else {
        echo 'Not set';
    }
?>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Sorry if it was a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<span class="detail">Status: <?php
    $status  = $property['raw']['field_3022'];
    $expired = ( strtotime($property['data']['field_3211']) < time() );

    switch (true) {
        case ($status == 5) : echo ($expired) ? 'Expired' : 'Active'; break;
        case ($status == 8) : echo 'Sold'; break;
        default             : echo 'Not set';
    }
?>
</span>
```